# Where can I find a good tutorial that explains Interface Builder terminology?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, interface-builder

I'm trying to use Xcode 4's Interface Builder, but I'm a bit lost when it comes to some of the terms being used.  I'm not familiar with File's Owner, delegates, controllers, etc.

Is there a good tutorial out there that can explain how to use Interface Builder, what these terms mean, and how I can use Interface Builder to properly connect my UI elements?

Comment: There is at least one developer video at apples developer portal from the WWDC 2010 with the topic interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html). Read it beginning to end.